# Python to SQL: list of lists

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am currently facing a problem in exporting a python list of list into mySQL DB. 
Iam using MySQLdb for the same and utilising the executemany command.

**For example, I have a list of list:**

```
k1=[[['Bob', 'Alfred', 'Jen'],
['123 Elm Street', '55 Ninth Ave', '1 Paved Rd'],
[00123, 34565, 30094],
['Newark', 'Salinas', 'Los Angeles'],
['NJ', 'CA', 'CA']],[['Bob1', 'Alfred1', 'Jen1'],
['123 Elm Street1', '55 Ninth Ave1', '1 Paved Rd1'],
[001231, 345651, 300941],
['Newark1', 'Salinas1', 'Los Angeles1'],
['NJ1', 'CA1', 'CA1']]]
```

**and I try (after initialising the cursor and the database to use):**

```
cursor.executemany('''INSERT INTO addresses
                 (name, street, zipcode, city, state)
                 VALUES
                 (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''',zip(k1))
```

**and I get an error:**

```
 _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Well, basically, I would like the names, street, zipcode, city and state from the list of list k1 to mySQL db table "addresses" with the corresponding field entries.

Would be greatful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Instead of apologizing if it looks ugly, read up on how to format things. You were using restructuredtext syntax.

Comment: Your list items have three entries each but your format string is expecting five. Another issue is that your list of list entries seem to represent columns rather than rows.

Comment: Paul, thats right. I do see the problem. What I would like to do is collect the 5 entries from the list of list (i.e ordering). Is this not possible using "zip"?

Comment: Falmarri, Sorry about that. Can you let me know what you did to get the list formatted? I did try indenting 4 spaces, but that didnt work: although it worked on other bits of code.

Comment: Zip is not your problem. SQL insert statements insert rows, not columns. You need to rearrange your data structure if you want to use that same SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your datastructure is really awkward. I'm assuming you wanted to transform k1 into this:

```
>>> sum([zip(*x) for x in k1], [])
<<< 
[('Bob', '123 Elm Street', 83, 'Newark', 'NJ'),
 ('Alfred', '55 Ninth Ave', 34565, 'Salinas', 'CA'),
 ('Jen', '1 Paved Rd', 30094, 'Los Angeles', 'CA'),
 ('Bob1', '123 Elm Street1', 665, 'Newark1', 'NJ1'),
 ('Alfred1', '55 Ninth Ave1', 345651, 'Salinas1', 'CA1'),
 ('Jen1', '1 Paved Rd1', 300941, 'Los Angeles1', 'CA1')]
```

Now you can do executemany:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO addresses (name, street, zipcode, city, state) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
data = sum([zip(*x) for x in k1], [])
cursor.executemany(sql, data)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is really a SQL question; let's just concentrate on getting the data in the right form before you even try to call executemany().

Your k1 example is a list of 2 lists, each of which inner lists is also a list of lists, which are names/address components. So you actually have a list of lists of lists. I don't know what's the point of the outer layer of list, but the inner layer seems amenable to zip.

Ignoring that outer layer, I think what you want is

```
zip(*k1[0])
```

Which yields sane-looking results for the first element in k1. Again, I don't know what the intent is behind repeating the same data in k1[0] and k1[1] so I won't try to guess what you will do with the further elements in k1.

Again, before worrying about how to integrate this with your SQL database, just try playing with it in the python interpreter:

```
>>> k1=[[['Bob', 'Alfred', 'Jen'],['123 Elm Street', '55 Ninth Ave', '1 Paved Rd'],[00123, 34565, 30094],['Newark', 'Salinas', 'Los Angeles'],['NJ', 'CA', 'CA']],[['Bob1', 'Alfred1', 'Jen1'],['123 Elm Street1', '55 Ninth Ave1', '1 Paved Rd1'],[001231, 345651, 300941],['Newark1', 'Salinas1', 'Los Angeles1'],['NJ1', 'CA1', 'CA1']]]
>>> zip(k1)
[([['Bob', 'Alfred', 'Jen'], ['123 Elm Street', '55 Ninth Ave', '1 Paved Rd'], [83, 34565, 30094], ['Newark', 'Salinas', 'Los Angeles'], ['NJ', 'CA', 'CA']],), ([['Bob1', 'Alfred1', 'Jen1'], ['123 Elm Street1', '55 Ninth Ave1', '1 Paved Rd1'], [665, 345651, 300941], ['Newark1', 'Salinas1', 'Los Angeles1'], ['NJ1', 'CA1', 'CA1']],)]
>>> k1[0]
[['Bob', 'Alfred', 'Jen'], ['123 Elm Street', '55 Ninth Ave', '1 Paved Rd'], [83, 34565, 30094], ['Newark', 'Salinas', 'Los Angeles'], ['NJ', 'CA', 'CA']]
>>> k = k1[0]
>>> zip(k)
[(['Bob', 'Alfred', 'Jen'],), (['123 Elm Street', '55 Ninth Ave', '1 Paved Rd'],), ([83, 34565, 30094],), (['Newark', 'Salinas', 'Los Angeles'],), (['NJ', 'CA', 'CA'],)]
>>> zip(k[0], k[1])
[('Bob', '123 Elm Street'), ('Alfred', '55 Ninth Ave'), ('Jen', '1 Paved Rd')]
>>> zip(k[0], k[1], k[2], k[3], k[4])
[('Bob', '123 Elm Street', 83, 'Newark', 'NJ'), ('Alfred', '55 Ninth Ave', 34565, 'Salinas', 'CA'), ('Jen', '1 Paved Rd', 30094, 'Los Angeles', 'CA')]
>>> zip(*k)
[('Bob', '123 Elm Street', 83, 'Newark', 'NJ'), ('Alfred', '55 Ninth Ave', 34565, 'Salinas', 'CA'), ('Jen', '1 Paved Rd', 30094, 'Los Angeles', 'CA')]
```

Comment: it still has to deal with 00123 turning into 83.

Comment: @Dr.J: Yup. The solutions that use a list comprehension to evaluate the outer layer ([zip(*x) for x in k1]) are nicer too. If what you want is a literal answer to the original question. I was trying to provide some insight into what zip is actually doing with this data, lead in the direction of showing how to use it properly, and how to understand and teach oneself what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to pass each list inside k1 (which each themselves contain a few lists) to zip, like this:

```
>>> [zip(*x) for x in k1]
[[('Bob', '123 Elm Street', 83, 'Newark', 'NJ'), ('Alfred', '55 Ninth Ave', 34565, 'Salinas', 'CA'), ('Jen', '1 Paved Rd', 30094, 'Los Angeles', 'CA')], [('Bob1', '123 Elm Street1', 665, 'Newark1
', 'NJ1'), ('Alfred1', '55 Ninth Ave1', 345651, 'Salinas1', 'CA1'), ('Jen1', '1 Paved Rd1', 300941,   'Los Angeles1', 'CA1')]]
>>>
```

Note too that your zip codes should be strings, not numbers, in order to preserve the leading zeroes, and avoid having them misparsed as things you don't intend (see the '83' zip code in there? It was 00123 I believe).

Comment: Yes Jonesy, that is what I wanted. Thanks a lot. Adding an outer "sum" solves the problem (as zeekay has suggested)

Answer (score 0):

If you get your data structure to look like this: (not formatting but organization. You need to represent rows rather than columns to do inserts into SQL.)

```
[        
    ['Bob',     '123 Elm Street',  00123, 'Newark',     'NJ'],        
    ['Alfred',   '55 Ninth Ave',    34565, 'Salinas',   'CA'],
    ['Jen',     '1 Paved Rd',      30094, 'Los Angeles','CA']
]
```

your SQL INSERT may have a chance of working.